# Finding row layout id in an ArrayAdapter methods

Tags: android, android-layout, android-arrayadapter, android-adapter

When extending [ArrayAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html) with the following [code by vogella.com](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html#tutorial_ownadapter):

```
public class MySimpleArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
  private final Context context;
  private final String[] values;

  public MySimpleArrayAdapter(Context context, String[] values) {
    super(context, R.layout.rowlayout, values); // 111
    this.context = context;
    this.values = values;
  }

  @Override
  public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
        .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.rowlayout, parent, false); // 222
    TextView textView = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.label);
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.icon);
    textView.setText(values[position]);
    // Change the icon for Windows and iPhone
    String s = values[position];
    if (s.startsWith("Windows7") || s.startsWith("iPhone")
        || s.startsWith("Solaris")) {
      imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.no);
    } else {
      imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ok);
    }

    return rowView;
  }
}
```

In the method `getView()` at the comment **"// 222"** - is it possible to find the row layout (which was already set in the constructor at the comment **"// 111"**) - or do you have to use the hardcoded value **R.layout.rowlayout** again (or store it for yourself in the constructor or static final variable)?

Comment: you may use `BaseAdapter` without calling `super` in constructor, there you may set custom inflating. in `ArrayAdapter<String>` it is also possible, but there is no need to override `getView), whole `super` calling has no matter. also get familiar with `ViewHolder` pattern

Comment: Misread your question at first. You can create a final int class variable that you set to your layout id, and use it instead of explicitly using the resource name. Outside of that, don't think so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot actually access the `resource` parameter passed to the constructor, since it's private to the `ArrayAdapter` class.

You could, however, call `super.getView()`, which will inflate a new View from the supplied resource id. See the [ArrayAdapter code](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.java):

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    return createViewFromResource(position, convertView, parent, mResource);
}
```

However, this presupposes  that the layout contains a `TextView` (with a particular id, that you must supply to the constructor too) or is a `TextView` itself, so it may not be valid in all cases.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class MySimpleArrayAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
  private final Context context;
  private final String[] values;
  LayoutInflater inflater;

  public MySimpleArrayAdapter(Context context, String[] values) {
    this.context = context;
    this.values = values;
    inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
        .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
  }

  @Override
  public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View rowView = null;
    if(position==13)
        rowView=inflate(R.layout.rowlayout, parent, false);
    else rowView=inflate(R.layout.rowlayout2, parent, false);
    TextView textView = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.label);
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.icon);
    //assuming same ids in both layouts
    textView.setText(values[position]);
    String s = values[position];
    if (s.startsWith("Windows7") || s.startsWith("iPhone")
        || s.startsWith("Solaris")) {
      imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.no);
    } else {
      imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ok);
    }

    return rowView;
  }

  @Override
  public String getItem(int position){
      return values[position];
  }

  @Override
  public int getCount(){
      return values.length;
  }

  @Override
  public long getItemId(int position) {
      return 0;
  }
}
```

I'm assuming you want multiple forms of row (different layouts) - check [`getViewTypeCount`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html#getItemViewType%28int%29) method usage

also check [`ViewHolder`](http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/smooth-scrolling.html) pattern (recycling/reuse `convertView`)

Comment: Do you care to explain, why have you removed the call to super constructor?

Comment: of course, because it does nothing... your `ArrayAdapter` extends my `BaseAdapter` and all what is doing `super` is saving values for automation, [check source here, init is called in every constructor](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/1.6_r2/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.java#ArrayAdapter.init%28android.content.Context%2Cint%2Cint%2Cjava.util.List%29)

Comment: Sorry, but I don't get the point of your answer - the `R.layout.rowlayout` id is still hardcoded in the `getView()` of your code. How is it better than the code in the original question (besides dropping the super constructor)?

Comment: is it a lot to do `if(position==13) inflate(R.layout.rowlayout, parent, false); else inflate(R.layout.rowlayout2, parent, false);` you also may use `switch/case` with `getItemViewType`